# Pyspark dataframe - Illegal values appearing in the column?

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

So I have a table (sample)

[image: table]

I'm using pyspark dataframe APIs to filter out the 'NOC's that has never won a gold medal and here's the code I write

First part of my code

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = spark.read.format("csv").options(header = 'true').load("D:\\datasets\\athlete_events.csv")



df = df1.na.replace('NA', '-')


countgdf = gdf.groupBy('NOC').agg(count('Medal').alias('No of Gold medals')).select('NOC').show()
```

It will generate the output

```
+---+
|NOC|
+---+
|POL|
|JAM|
|BRA|
|ARM|
|MOZ|
|JOR|
|CUB|
|FRA|
|ALG|
|BRN|
+---+
only showing top 10 rows
```

The next part of the code is something like

```
allgdf  = df.select('NOC').distinct()
```

This display the output

```
+-----------+
|        NOC|
+-----------+
|   DeRuyter|
|        POL|
|     Russia|
|        JAM|
|        BUR|
|        BRA|
|        ARM|
|        MOZ|
|        CUB|
|        JOR|
|     Sweden|
|        FRA|
|        ALG|
|        SOM|
|        IVB|
|Philippines|
|        BRN|
|        MAL|
|        COD|
|        FSM|
+-----------+
```

Notice the values that are more than 3 characters? Those are supposed to be the values of the column 'Team' but I'm not sure why those values are getting displayed in 'NOC' column. It's hard to figure out why this is happening i.e illegal values in the column.

When I write the final code

```
final = allgdf.subtract(countgdf).show()
```

The same happens as illegal values appear in the final dataframe column.

Any help would be appericiated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a delimiter for your CSV file. By default Spark is using comma separators (,)

This can be done, for example, with :

```
.option("delimiter",";")
```

Comment: Can you share some "corrupted" lines ? ie: including DeRuyter